# Calculating a matrix-vector product efficiently without inverse operation

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, inverse, matlab, positive-definite

Given a matrix $A=I+K^{-1}BB^TK^{-1}$ where K is a discrete Laplacian, and B is a sparse uniformly distributed random matrix, how can I calculate matrix-vector products $Av$ efficiently without any inverse operations?

I'm supposed to use the \ operator, but not sure where that fits in, given that $Av=b$, but I know $v$, i.e. unlike usual $Ax=b$ problems where you solve for $x$ given b.

$A$ is positive definite so can be split into $RR^T$, giving:

$(I+RR^T)v=b$

where $R=K^{-1}B$

Comment: You can write $K^{-1}BB^{T}K^{-1}v$ as $K^{-1}(B(B^{T}(K^{-1}v)))$ and use $K\backslash v$ to compute $K^{-1}v$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, so I have $Av=I*v+K\backslash (B(B'(K\backslash  V))$, although one issue I'm running into now with large N is that creating the identity matrix exceeds maximum array size?

Comment: Resolved using `speye()`!!

Comment: Why would you need an identity matrix, just add $x$ to the answer from the first comment.